# Is there a way to replace a modal's content div by clicking on a main page div?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

On the images index page have a long list of photos each with a unique id, and a uniform class. I'm using Ruby on Rails, but the html output looks like this about 20 times for each image:

```
<div id="A unique number" class="myImages" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img src="my.images.url">
</div>
```

Essentially, of the twenty images on my index page, each one gets a unique id, but they all belong to `myImages` `toggle="modal"` and `target="#myModal"`

My modal looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far, I've been trying to replace the `"modal-body"` using jquery like this:

```
$(".myImages").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        var content = $(this).html();
        $(".modal-body").replaceWith('<div class="replaced">'+content+'</div>');
})
```

And I've also tried:

```
$(".myImages").on('click', function(){
    $(".modal-body").replaceWith('.myImages')
})
```

I think I need to somehow reference the *id* of the div I click on to use in my jquery. Something like

```
$("#<%= dynamically_use_id_of_div_I_Clicked_On %>").on('click',function({
  -code that replaces the modal div with the image tag-
})
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".myImages").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".modal-body").html($(this).html());
});
```

Please find this [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/nvzte69x/)

Comment: I couldn't get that one to work for me. The modal still pops up fine, but the `modal-body` is still just ". . ."

Comment: @RyanOliverLanham I have added a jsfiddle